# Jface TreeViewer diposed during refresh()

Tags: eclipse, tree, jface

what if I do a `viewer.refresh()` at the same time I close the tree viewer on the UI.

What will happen and how I can handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't happen in the same time, as UI events (such as close or refresh) are inherently single-threaded - they can happen only one after the other (unless you call refresh inside the dispose, or dispose during refresh, however both of them are hard to justify as normal steps)..

If your question was motivated by an SWT error of widget is disposed, then most likely you have disposed of something previously, but nonetheless called its refresh method - I would look it at that way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have more than one listener and trees around? I would advice to add a disposeListener to the tree and put a breakpoint into it. Then you see when it gets disposed.